# How can I update a vsts pull request after a release finishes?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to find the configuration required for using VSTS external services to make a VSTS release required to be successful before the PR to master can be completed.
The workflow is:
Create PR -> Triggers Build -> On Success Triggers Release -> On Success will flag the PR as OK.

Is there a way to do this using external services to post a successful status?

Comment: I am afraid you can't, how about move tasks in release to build?

Comment: That defeats the process of separating out builds from releases.

Answer (score 0):

For the release definition, you can triggerred by the PR validation build artifacts, so you can get the pull request id by the pre-definied variable `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceBranch`.

Assume the artifact alias for the release definition is `prvalid`, then you can get the pull request id (as the variable `$id` below) with  below script:

```
$id="$(Release.Artifacts.prvalid.SourceBranch)".Split('/')
echo $id
$id=$id[2]
```

And then you can get the source branch and target branch by [the REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#get-a-pull-request):

```
GET https://acount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/repoID/pullRequests/PRid?api-version=3.0
```

Then you can merge the source branch into tartget branch, and the PR status will be `completed`.